# grep remove exact matches from line without removing the whole line

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have patterns.txt file and I would like to remove all exact matches of patterns from FILE.txt. The FILE.txt is the following:

```
word1 word2
word3 word4
word5 word6
```

The pattern file contains:

```
word1
word6
```

The expected output is:

```
word2
word3 word4
word5
```

The command below removes the whole row where there is an exact match. How can I only remove the exact match from a line without removing the whole line? I don't want to use for-loops to achieve this.

```
cat FILE.txt | grep -wvf pattern.txt
```

Comment: Shouldn't last line be `line5`? In your expected sample output, please confirm once.

Comment: @Marc : `grep` is the  wrong tool for this. You could go for `sed` or write a small program explicitly (say, in Ruby or Perl, or whatever language you feel comfortable with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
re=$(tr '\n' '|' < patterns.txt)
sed -r "s/$re//; s/^[[:space:]]*//" file
word2
word3 word4
word5
```

---

Note: Make sure `patterns.txt` does not have a trailing new line or extra new lines since `|` will end up in each of those positions.

Comment: Also make sure that `patterns.txt` has no other special meta regex characters such as `. + ( ) { } [ ]` etc

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {pats[$1]; next} {more=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (!($i in pats)) printf "%s", (more++ ? OFS : "") $i; print ""}' patterns.txt file

word2
word3 word4
word5
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk '
FNR == NR {
   pats[$1]
   next
}
{
   more = 0
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if (!($i in pats))
         printf "%s", (more++ ? OFS : "") $i
   print ""
}' patterns.txt file
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to split the text with a word (string) as a delimiter, you can use awk.

```
awk -F 'word' '{print $1;print $2}' file.txt
```

In case you want to display only what is after the delimiter then it would be:

```
awk -F 'word' '{print $2}' file.txt
```

In order to change the pattern continuously then you might have to create a loop.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to do just what [@anubhava did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69722507/7552). Then I thought that perl might be good for that: perl has good capabilities for filtering lists. The problem is that perl doesn't have an FNR variable. But I played around with `a2p` and came up with this:

```sh
perl -lane '
    $FNR = $. - $FNRbase;
    if ($. == $FNR) {
      $ignore{$F[0]} = 1;
    } else {
      print join " ", grep {not exists $ignore{$_}} @F;
    }
  } continue {
    $FNRbase = $. if eof
' pattern.txt FILE.txt
```

Comment: `perl -lne  'if (!$eof) { push @E,$_ } else { foreach $e (@E) { s/\Q$e\E//g } print } $eof=$eof||eof' pattern.txt FILE.txt`  if an eof isn't yet passed, save pattern in @E, else remove all patterns and print.  At end of per-line processing, calculate $eof.  The `\Q\E` around the pattern allow the pattern to have any special characters.